# XPM Session Storage configuration for JNDI

Tags: content-delivery, experience-manager

I can use a JNDI name in my storage_conf.xml file for the standard content delivery database, but.  This is great as we can create a single storage file that is used in all environments and remains part of the same deployment package.

We'd seen that this doesn't work when configuring a <storage> element within a <Wrapper> (the new nodes for session preview)

```xml
<Wrappers>
  <Wrapper Name="SessionWrapper">
    <storage />
  </Wrapper>
</Wrappers>
```

we believe that SDL Tridion doesn't support a JNDI name at the moment for this format, which is something I will confirm with SDL Tridion support.   In the event this is indeed not supported, I was wondering what work arounds the community has made in an attempt to create a single deployment package (war file) that can be used in all SDL Tridion environments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JNDI cannot currently be used for "storage wrappers" as you state, so the solution is not very easy - unless all your environments are using the same wrapper database - which is not such a crazy thing, after all this database only has temporary data in it.

The way I'm dealing with it right now is with post-deployment scripts that modify ##variables## in the cd_*_conf.xml files. Not elegant, but effective.

Comment: Thanks Nuno.  Both points are very good ideas.  We don't have he single session preview, so the idea of ##variables## is the winner here.

Comment: Just so everyone knows, 2013 will support JNDI for the session wrapper.